# wp_update_post on specific custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-update-post

first of all, im sorry for my poor english, when i upadte a post this code changes the post slug to a "profileid" costom field value..

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_custom_slug');
function my_custom_slug($post_id) {


     //Check it's not an auto save routine
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;
 //Perform permission checks! For example:
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) 
        return; 
    //If calling wp_update_post, unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'my_custom_slug');
    //call wp_update_post update, which calls save_post again. E.g:
        wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_name' =>get_post_meta($post_id,'profileid',true)));
    // re-hook this function
    add_action('save_post', 'my_custom_slug');
}
```

it works fine, but how i can use this for only a specific custom post type?
my custom post type is "masters"..
i used this, but not works!
anyone can help?

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_custom_slug');
function my_custom_slug($post_id) {


    $slug = 'masters';
    // If this isn't a 'masters' post, don't update it.
    if ( $slug != $post->post_type )
        return $post_id;


     //Check it's not an auto save routine
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;
 //Perform permission checks! For example:
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) 
        return; 
    //If calling wp_update_post, unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'my_custom_slug');
    //call wp_update_post update, which calls save_post again. E.g:
        wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_name' =>get_post_meta($post_id,'profileid',true)));
    // re-hook this function
    add_action('save_post', 'my_custom_slug');
}
```

Comment: How you call this function in submit form? I'm trying something like that but when I submit the form, nothing  happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop executing the function if the post is not of a specific post type. You can use [`get_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) for this.

```
if( 'masters' != get_post_type( $post_id ) )
  return;
```

Comment: tnx a lot man...!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the action `save_post`, use `"save_post_{$post->post_type}"` instead. It fires right before `save_post`, and you get the same information.

Example for the post type `masters`:

```
add_action( 'save_post_masters', 'my_custom_slug', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_slug( $post_id, \WP_Post $post ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/* check for your post type only */

```
    function your_function_name( $post_id ) {
        global $post;  

        //skip auto save

        //......

        if( $post->post_type == "your_post_type" ) {
                if( isset($_POST['your_post_id']) ) { update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_post_id', $_POST['your_post_id'] );}
            }
}
```