# Undefined index: post in NOTICE while adding meta box

Tags: pages, metabox

I am trying to add meta box on particular page with id 62. But i get the notice `Undefined index: post in` in line 5 i.e `$post_id= $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];`

Following is the code i am using.

```
<?php 
add_action('admin_init','contact_meta_init1');

function contact_meta_init1(){   
    $post_id= $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];    
    if($post_id=='62'){
      add_meta_box('contact_meta11','Social icons','social_icon','page','normal','high');       
    }
  }

function social_icon()
  {      
    global $post;    
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="contactmeta_noncename" id="contactmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';     
    $contact_no = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_contact_no', true);        
     echo '<label >';?><?php _e( 'contact_no:' );?></label>
    <?php echo '<br><textarea name=_contact_no rows="1" cols="90">'.$contact_no.'</textarea>';   
}

function contact_meta_save1($post_id, $post) {  
  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( ($_POST['contactmeta_noncename']), plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
  return $post->ID;
  }
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
    return $post->ID;   
  $contact_meta['_contact_no'] = $_POST['_contact_no'];  

  foreach ($contact_meta as $key => $value) { 
    if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; 
    $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // 
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { 
      update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    } else { 
      add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    }
    if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); 
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'contact_meta_save1', 1, 2);
?>
```

I did some reasearch , then i used isset like this

```
$post_id= isset($_GET['post']) ? isset($_GET['post']) : isset($_POST['post_ID']);
```

This help to get the rid of the notices but then this metabox is added to all of the pages.

I have used this code lot of times , but this time don't what is wrong.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error, because the `$_GET` and `$_POST` are not filled on every admin page with that data. Also, your code should never rely on globals, they can be changed by any other code, so they are not reliable. So don't use `global $post;`, `$_POST` or `$_GET` when you can get the information from better sources like here.

Use the action `add_meta_boxes` to … well … add metaboxes. If you want to restrict the metabox to just one post type use the action `add_meta_boxes_$post_type`.

Here is how you register a metabox for the post type `page`, and how to access the `WP_Post` object in your callback function:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', function( \WP_Post $post ) {

    if ( 62 === (int) $post->ID ) {
        add_meta_box( 'contact_meta11','Social icons','social_icon','page','normal','high' );
    }
});

function social_icon( \WP_Post $post ) {

}
```

*Note:* In my example, I write `\WP_Post`, not just `WP_Post`, because this class exists in the global [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php). I hope you are using your own namespace for your code. In that case, you have to write it like I did, because other wise PHP would try – and fail – to find the class in your namespace.

Comment: thanks a lot... you just saved my life. Suddenly was facing this problem in 2 -3 projects. But some things are not clear, why can't use global $post. For the first time saw \WP_Post $post   . May be need to study what it is

Comment: @terminator I made an update to my answer to explain both points better.

Comment: thanks for the update. Then should i use  \WP_Post $post in every case in my code like in this      function contact_meta_save1($post_id, $post)  ?

Comment: @terminator Yes, that will also help your IDE to provide auto-complete on the members of the object.

Comment: But if i use like function my_meta_save( \WP_Post $post) ;    i get this error -> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to my_meta_save() must be an instance of WP_Post, integer given in

Comment: The `save_post_page` action receives the post ID as first argument and the post _object_ as the second. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/194932/73) for an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26002/discussion-between-terminator-and-toscho).